# Splitting Strings in R by data type

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector like:
"XY13DJ" "J114HD" "E63NP"  "F161JU" "AM76NZ" "PMI79DU"

I need to divide to two vectors like "XY J E F AM PMI"  and "13DJ,114HD,63NP,161JU 76NZ,79DU".

in the string, whenever the first digit comes, data should be split.

I've written code like this which is not working:

```
enter code here
vector_1 = c()
vector_2 = c()
string_split <- function(ele){
    val <- regexpr('[0-9]',ele)[1]
    fn <- substr(ele,0,val-1)
    ln <- substr(ele,val,nchar(ele))
    vector_1 <- append(vector_1,fn)
    vector_2 <- append(vector_2,ln)
}
sapply(vector-to-pass, string_split)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this or omit the `as.list` if you want it as a two column data frame:

```
as.list(read.table(text = sub("(\\d)", " \\1", x), as.is = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
$V1
[1] "XY"  "J"   "E"   "F"   "AM"  "PMI"

$V2
[1] "13DJ"  "114HD" "63NP"  "161JU" "76NZ"  "79DU"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R solution which splits by an empty element based on positive lookahead and lookbehinds:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(vec, "(?<=\\p{L})(?=\\d+\\p{L}+$)", perl = TRUE)))
```

or you can also use `str_match` from `stringr` to match the capturing groups:

```
library(stringr)
as.data.frame(str_match(vec, "(^\\p{L}+)(\\d+\\p{L}+$)")[,-1])
```

**Result:**

```
   V1    V2
1  XY  13DJ
2   J 114HD
3   E  63NP
4   F 161JU
5  AM  76NZ
6 PMI  79DU
```

**Data:**

```
vec = c("XY13DJ", "J114HD", "E63NP", "F161JU", "AM76NZ", "PMI79DU")
```